# Printing authors in descending order per sold copies per year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
create table AUTHORS 
(
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(30)
)

create table BOOKS
(
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(30),
    year integer,
    sold_copies integer,
    author_id integer references AUTHORS (id)
)
```

How would I create a table with authors in descending order per sold copies of books per year in pgAdmin4 (PostgreSQL) ?

im a beginner and I am not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need to create a new table. A simple SELECT will do (maybe stored inside a view)

```
select a.id, a.name, b.year, sum(b.sold_copies) as total_copies
from author a
  join books b on b.author_id = a.id
group by a.id, a.name, b.year
order by sum(b.sold_copies) desc;
```